# 2 boxes, 2 dynamic maximums changing when one is set

Tags: php, javascript

I've got this code which sets dynamic maximum values for two text boxes:

```
var length = document.getElementById('firstBox'),
    width = document.getElementById('secondBox');
    max1 = 100;
    min1 = 20;
    max2 = 200;
    min2 = 10;

length.onchange = function() {
    var maxValue, minValue;

    if (width.value < max1) {
        maxValue = max2;
        minValue = (width.value < min1) ? min1 : min2;
    } else {
        maxValue = max1;
        minValue = min1;
    }
    if (this.value > maxValue) {
        this.value = maxValue;
    }
    if (this.value < minValue) {
        this.value = minValue;
    }
};

width.onchange = function() {
    var maxValue, minValue;

    if (length.value < max1) {
        maxValue = max2;
        minValue = (length.value < min1) ? min1 : min2;
    } else {
        maxValue = max1;
        minValue = min1;
    }
    if (this.value > maxValue) {
        this.value = maxValue;
    }
    if (this.value < minValue) {
        this.value = minValue;
    }
};
```

It works very well, only I would like to have the maximum (max2) switch to the other box if the customer types in a value higher than the lowest maximum (max1) in that box.

Say a customer types "150" in box one, then that box automatically gets assigned max2 "200" - but what I want, is if the customer then also types "150" or any value higher than max1 in the second box, then that should become the max2, meaning the first box will be lowered from it's "150" to "100" as is the max1. And vice versa.

Hopefully that's understandable, otherwise let me know and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you actually want is to have the size constrained either in horizontal or vertical layout?

Comment: Yes, although what I'm really looking for here is a way to override the set maximum when the value is higher.

Comment: override the maximum no matter what value? will 400 be legitimate in the current settings?

Comment: If someone enters 400 or any value higher than 200, then that box should automatically get the highest max while the other box will get changed to fit the lowest max, if it already exceeds it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is instead of holding the variables `firstbox` and `secondbox` to hold pointer variables to the box that conforms to max1 `max1box` and the box that conforms to max2, `max2box`.

In the case the logic dictates to switch maxes, you just switch the pointers around.

```
var max1box = document.getElementById('length'),
    max2box = document.getElementById('width');
    max1 = 100;
    min1 = 20;
    max2 = 200;
    min2 = 10;

max1box.addEventListener('change',validateValues);
max2box.addEventListener('change',validateValues);

function validateValues() {

    if (this == max1box && this.value > max1 && this.value > max2box.value)
    {
       max1box = max2box; 
       max2box = this;  
    } 

    if (max1box .value > max1) {
        max1box .value = max1;
    }
    if (max1box .value < min1) {
        max1box .value = min1;
    }        

    if (max2box.value > max2) {
        max2box.value = max2;
    }
    if (max2box.value < min2) {
        max2box.value = min2;
    }
   }
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hm2Qn/1/

The rules when to switch might not be exactly what you need but you can take it from here.

Comment: I can't get it to work Variant. In your example I can type whatever I like, even more than the maximums. In theory, it should go down to 200 when I leave the box, but I typed "125258" and it remained.

Comment: works great for me... what browser are you using? does it work for you in the jsfiddle ?

Comment: I'm using Firefox - just tested it in IE, and it works. Any chance you can get it to work in FF as well, Variant?

Comment: Also, it appears only the "Width" box has the ability to override all. Meaning, if I type 200 in Width, then I can't get the Length box to become max by entering a high value. Only vice versa.